# Jolt spec for nifi - removing attributes

Tags: apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I am newbie in NiFi. I am trying to remove some attributes (e.g. name in Swedish and Chinese, images from description, etc.) with `JoltTransformJSON`, with 'limited' success. Could you please help me? Many thanks in advance!
Alicia

Details as below: 
`JoltTransformJSON` properties set as:

```
Jolt Transformation DSL: Remove
Jolt Specification: {"name": {"sv": "", "zh": ""}, "source_type": "", "description": {"image": {"url": "", "copyright_holder":"", "license_type": ""}}}
```

All the attributes:

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "name": {
      "fi": "string",
      "en": "string",
      "sv": "string",
      "zh": "string"
    },
    "source_type": {},
    "info_url": "string",
    "modified_at": "2019-12-27T16:34:17.896Z",
    "location": {
      "lat": {},
      "lon": {},
      "address": {
        "street_address": "string",
        "postal_code": "string",
        "locality": "string"
      }
    },
    "description": {
      "intro": "string",
      "body": "string",
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "string",
          "copyright_holder": "string",
          "license_type": {}
        }
      ]
    },
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": "string",
        "name": "string"
      }
    ],
    "where_when_duration": {
      "where_and_when": "string",
      "duration": "string"
    }
  }
]
```

The problem is that transformation (removing specified fields) is not performed. The expected result should be:

```
    "id": "string",
    "name": {
      "fi": "string",
      "en": "string"
      },
    "info_url": "string",
    "modified_at": "2019-12-27T16:34:17.896Z",
    "location": {
      "lat": {},
      "lon": {},
      "address": {
        "street_address": "string",
        "postal_code": "string",
        "locality": "string"
      }
    },
    "description": {
      "intro": "string",
      "body": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": "string",
        "name": "string"
      }
    ],
    "where_when_duration": {
      "where_and_when": "string",
      "duration": "string"
    }
  }
```

How can I remove unwanted fields? 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: it's not clear which attributes you wish to remove. Are these the "All the attributes" ones?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to remove all that I specified, meaning: ```{"name": {"sv": "", "zh": ""}, "source_type": "", "description": {"image": {"url": "", "copyright_holder":"", "license_type": ""}}}``` and I would like to keep the rest.

Comment: So what is the problem with your json, apart from using "image" instead of "images"? Also, do you wish to remove the "images" array, remove all of its elements or remove all of its elements' elements?

Comment: The problem is that transformation (removing specified fields) is not performed. I have just added a listing for the expected result - in the main question. Many thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

According to your expected result, your wanted jolt specification is:

```
{
  "name": {
    "sv": "",
    "zh": ""
  },
  "source_type": "",
  "description": {
    "images": ""
  }
}
```